# Qt: How to go back and forth between the WYSIWYG editor and C++ code?

Tags: c++, qt, layout, widget, designer

I'm a newbie to Qt. I'm using Qt Creator and a QT Widget Project. The QT widget project comes with a WYSIWYG editor, which I think is called Qt Designer, that seems great. But I want to be able to access the C++ code that governs all of the widgets I'm using. Right now I only have access to the widget that I defined myself; for the others (things like buttons, tables, spin boxes etc) I don't know how to see their code; I can only see the XML that governs their formatting.

Also, working in reverse, I want to be able to take some of the example projects and code that I see on the internet and edit them in Qt Designer, or at least discover how to incorporate them into something I've built with it. A lot of the examples have really cool stuff going on that I would like to try, but they generally don't seem to use Qt Designer for their layouts and frankly I'm kind of mystified as to how the layout is managed in a lot of cases. I see lots of documentation on how to build this or that object, but I haven't as yet found the bridge I need to take that knowledge and add to it how to arrange the objects you've built in a layout.

So I have a little knowledge of how to program objects, and a little knowledge of how to build a layout, but not much knowledge of how to build objects within a layout or import someone else's object into a layout I built. Advice in either of these specific areas would be great, or you could give me some good starting points - I know the obvious answer is to read documentation, but Qt is so vast that it's a bit difficult to know what to look at.

Answer (score 1):

> for the others (things like buttons, tables, spin boxes etc) I don't
>   know how to see their code

It's called Qt's source code, and you can download it from the Qt website.

> I can only see the XML that governs their formatting.

See Simon's answer.

> I want to be able to take some of the example projects and code that I
>   see on the internet and edit them in Qt Designer, or at least discover
>   how to incorporate them into something I've built with it. A lot of
>   the examples have really cool stuff going on that I would like to try,
>   but they generally don't seem to use Qt Designer for their layouts and
>   frankly I'm kind of mystified as to how the layout is managed in a lot
>   of cases.

Many people don't use the designer much (me included), generally because it favours more static UIs.  The layout is managed via `QLayout` derived classes, which are also represented in Qt Designer.

> I know the obvious answer is to read documentation

Yes it is, and Qt's documentation is some of the finest out there.  I think this particular [example](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-calendarwidget.html) should help you along.

Answer (score 0):

Qt Creator creates for every form corresponding cpp/h-files.

Each file has an object called "ui", which you use to access all your stuff on the form.

E.g. you have a Combobox called "comboBox1", you would set it to a value with

```
ui->comboBox1->setCurrentindex(1);
```

You should not modify all the moc_*.cpp or ui_*.h files, as they are generated by Qt.